# WordPress Pagination with Get Value

Tags: pagination

I have allow readers to select the posts order with different parameters. For a example users can order posts by "vote". (Vote is a custom post type.)

Then URL will be `http://example.com/?sort_by_type=vote`

I have used `pre_get_posts` action to do orderthe posts. It works fine. The problem is pagination .

Pagination look like this in my theme.

```
http://example.com/?sort_by_type=vote/page/2/
```

But it should be `http://example.com/page/2/?sort_by_type=vote` to work correctly.

So how I correct pagination?

---

Edit After comment of @govind : The theme which I used is a not a theme developed by me. What I did i, if URL contain `?sort_by_type=vote` request I changed the post order using `pre_get_posts` filter.

When I cheeking theme I found following code.

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) : // If viewing the blog, an archive, or search results. ?>

    <?php loop_pagination(
        array( 
            'prev_text' => _x( '&larr; Previous', 'posts navigation', 'daily' ), 
            'next_text' => _x( 'Next &rarr;',     'posts navigation', 'daily' )
        ) 
    ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what function did you use to get the website current page url ? please show me your code.

Comment: @GovindKumar I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom pagination using `paginate_link()` function and add custom query string after current url.

To add argument to the links of paginations you can pass them as array argument inside the 'add_args'

```
if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) : 

    echo paginate_links(array(
         'base' => preg_replace('/\?.*/', '/', get_pagenum_link(1)) . '%_%',
         'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
         'format' => 'page/%#%',
         'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
         // here you can pass custom query string to the pagination url
         'add_args' => array(
             'sort_by_type' => ( !empty($_GET['sort_by_type']) ) ? $_GET['sort_by_type'] : 'vote'
         )
     ));    

endif;
```

Replace your pagination code with this above code.

It will print all string with custom query string.
`http://example.com/page/2/?sort_by_type=vote`

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You should define a new pagination function for do it.

```
<?php
function custom_pagination() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s?sort_by_type=vote</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s?sort_by_type=vote</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s?sort_by_type=vote</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```